# blackjack open vs close

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

Assuming 3 players; A,B and C play a game of blackjack where the game is simplified with each player being dealt with exactly 2 cards each. And there are no Hit, Stand, Double down, Split, or Surrender. And it is a fair and well shuffled 52 cards deck.

From my prior post, I understand that as long as the players are only able to see the cards in their hand, the possibilities are equal among the 3 players $\binom{52}{2}$ regardless of whether the cards are dealt in group of 2 or 1 at a time from one player to another.

However, if we were to tweak the rules of game that the first card for each player will be dealt opened with player A being dealt first, player B second and player C third;

player A first open card = 5 of spades
player B first open card = 2 of hearts
player C first open card = 2 of diamonds

After all three open cards are dealt, the sequences of how the closed cards will be dealt is the same; player A first, player B second and player C third.

Does the possibilities now change to:

player A: (52)(52-3) 
player B: (52-1)(52-4) 
player C: (52-2)(52-5)

Kindly advise

Comment: How do you define an "*outcome*" here?  Do you define an outcome as just what player $A$ has without regards to the order in which the cards arrived and without regard to what anyone else has?  Do you define an outcome as what player $A$ has and the order in which the cards arrived but without regard to what anyone else has?  Do you define an outcome as what every player has and the order in which they arrived?  Do you define an outcome as what player $A$ has and what player $A$ *can see* of the other player's hands without regard to what player $A$ can not see?  Something else?

Comment: It depends on what you are counting.  Each player has $52\times 51$  possibilities for that player's two cards, counting visible or not as different.  For the deal as a whole, you can say there are  $52 \times 51 \times 50 \times 49 \times 48 \times 47$ (which is the product of what you have stated at the end)  rather than $(52\times 51)^3$ possibilities

Comment: When asking how many outcomes a scenario has, you must be very specific about what it is you want to count.  There are many very similarly worded but distinct counting problems that can be asked about a scenario with different answers.  Also... following from what I suggested last time... don't write binomial coefficients with $1$'s as the bottom... it makes it unnecessarily wordy.  You could just as easily have written the above as $52\cdot 49$, as $51\cdot 48$ and as $50\cdot 47$ in far fewer symbols, in larger font, in a more easily readable fashion.

Comment: @JMoravitz, outcome in the order which the first open cards are dealt to each players. After player A is dealt with his first open card (ie. 5 of spades), player B knows that 5 of spades is not longer available, and after player B is dealt with this first open card(ie. 2 of hearts), player C knows that 5 of spades and 2 of hearts are no longer in the deck. Will be editing out the 1's, thanks

Comment: For what it is worth, the exact differences between the specific counting problems you might be interested in (*if order matters, if cards made visible, etc...*) although change the *counting problems* might be irrelevant for related questions about *probabilities*.  So long as you are consistent in your choices for numerator and denominator (*and are correctly approaching the problem*) the answer for a probability question will be the same regardless whether or not you treated order as relevant or not or other similar differences.  The extra factors essentially cancelling out in the fraction.

Comment: To recap: The number of possible hands that player $A$ can have where we ignore the order in which the cards are received and we ignore what everyone else has is indeed $\binom{52}{2}$.  Similarly, the number of possible hands that $B$ can have where we ignore the order in which the cards are received and we ignore what everyone else has is also $\binom{52}{2}$.  The number of possible ways that players $A,B,C$ can all receive their cards simultaneously where we ignore the order in which the cards are received but we do keep track of who received what card and what all have is...

Comment: ... $\binom{52}{2}\cdot\binom{50}{2}\cdot\binom{48}{2}$.  The number of possibilities where we keep track of who received what card *and* in what order is $52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48\cdot 47$.  That is true regardless whether or not the first card for each player were turned over...  These are all similarly worded problems but differ in nuance and you should not get the questions mixed up.  Your concern seems to be "one answer is different than another" but that is because they were answering different problems.

Comment: @JMoravitz, the wording is causing a lot confusing when trying to work through these sort of questions for me. And the exercises from the textbook(intro to probability) I'm working on don't have 90% of its answer available(self study). Hence, I'm totally clueless whether i am correct or wrong. And answers found online are sometimes fill with debates among contributors, hence, making it even more confusing at time.

Comment: @JMoravitz, one more question. when you mentioned "but we do keep track of who received what card and what all have is...$\binom{52}{2} \binom{50}{2} \binom{48}{2}$", you meant in real gaming situation right?